# Boton dentro de Navbar asp.net

Tags: c#, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Hola soy nuevo en la programación web y estoy incursionando en el mundo MVC y BOOTSTRAP. 
tengo este código en el cual quiero poner un botón en vez de un `link` en la navbar que viene por defecto en ASP.NET, me gustaria que "Register" y "log in" tengan la clase btn-primary.Espero que me puedan ayudar. Gracias!

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">   
  <li>
    @Html.ActionLink("Registrarse", "Register", "Account",       routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id =       "registerLink" })</li> <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ingreso al   Sistema", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Este es el codigo.    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registrarse", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ingreso al Sistema", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>

Comment: cual es el codigo que tienes? porque no lo has publicado

Comment: <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Registrarse", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Ingreso al Sistema", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>

Comment: pero no es un proyecto asp.net, sino que es asp.net mvc? deberias cambiar el tag de la pregunta

Comment: perdon soy nuevo en la pagina, ahora edito el tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">   
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Registrarse", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink", @class= "btn-primary" })
    </li> 
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Ingreso al   Sistema", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class= "btn-primary" })
    </li> 
</ul>
```

asi como atributo defines el id puedes definir el `class` (esta al final del codigo) para asignar el requerido por bootstrap

Comment: gracias leandro me sirvio! solo quisiera saber porque se ven tan grandes,

Comment: lo hice antonio pero igualmente los botones adoptan el ancho de la navbar, se te ocurre porque puede ser?